# Mousedown Timer using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousedown

How can I know how long a user has been holding the mouse button down (anywhere on a webpage)? I want to execute a function when the user held the mouse button for at least 2-3 seconds (preferably cancelling the mouse down in the process). Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(window).mousedown(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
    this.downTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        // do your thing 
    }, 2000);
}).mouseup(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Pe9sq/2/

Answer (score 1):

Off hand I would experiment with `$("body").mousedown(function(){})` using jQuery and `$("body").mouseup(function(){})`. I guess you can start a timer which will call function in 2 to 3 seconds. If the `mouseup` event occurs, then you can cancel the timer. You could probably test it with a simple script but you might have to look at cases where the `click` might have occurred because a link or button was clicked on the page. But as a starting point I would experiment with the `$("body").mousedown` and `$("body").mouseup`. If I have chance I'll see if I can send a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function WhateverYoudLikeToExecWithinNext3Seconds(){
    // Code goes here.
}

element.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){WhateverIdLikeToExecWithin3Seconds();}, 3000);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one.
http://jsfiddle.net/b1Lzo60n/

Mousedown starts a timer that checks if mouse is still down after 1 second.

```
<button id="button">Press me</button>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Code:

```
var mousedown = false;
var mousedown_timer = '';
$('#button').mousedown(function(e) {
    mousedown = true;
    $('#log').text('mousedown...');
    mousedown_timer = setTimeout(function() {
        if(mousedown) {
            $('#log').text('1 second');
        }
    }, 1000);
}).mouseup(function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
    clearTimeout(mousedown_timer);
    $('#log').text('aborted');
});
```