# jQuery - How to chain event on appended selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to adapt the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10409126/1154380) to a jQuery appended element, without using any "flag" variables.

Original code is :

```
$(window).mousedown(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
    this.downTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('mousedown > 2 sec');   
    }, 2000); 
}).mouseup(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(this.downTimer); 
});​
```

So I can't see how to use it with `document` :

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.item', function(){
// How to chain mouseup ? 
});
```

I've tried with

```
$(document).find('.item')
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done using chaining, because `.on()` returns the object it was called on, and that doesn't include the selector that it delegates to.

Instead, you can put the event bindings in an object.

```
$(document).on({
    mousedown: function() { ... },
    mouseup: function() { ... }
}, '.item');
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, this snippet is a working example of `mousedown`/`mouseup` timer delegation via chained event handlers. The chaining works on the `document` element, not on the delegated descendant, but the end result seems to match up with the behavior you're looking for.

Here, `this` is the filtered the descendant element that is actually the event target.

```js
$(document)
  .on('mousedown', '.has_timer', function() {
    clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
    $('#this_identity').text(this.className);
    this.downTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      alert('mousedown > 2 sec');
    }, 2000);
  })
  .on('mouseup', '.has_timer', function() {
     clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
  });
```

```css
.has_timer {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
.no_timer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
.this_test {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="has_timer first_has_timer">This element has a mousedown timer.</div>
<div class="no_timer">This element does not have a timer.</div>
<div class="has_timer other_has_timer">This other element has a mousedown timer.</div>
<div class="no_timer">This other element does not have a timer.</div>
<div class="this_test">"this" className: <span id="this_identity"></span></div>
```