# How to detect a long press on a div in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, triggers

I would like to execute some function when the user presses for `2 seconds` on a div.

Is it possible ?

Here is my code to detect the click on the div

```
$('div').mousedown(function() {

});
```

Comment: This post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091026/mousedown-timer-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [Long Press in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just watch both `mousedown` and `mouseup` and calculate the difference. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/PdJDe/).

```
(function() { 

    // how many milliseconds is a long press?
    var longpress = 3000;
    // holds the start time
    var start;

    jQuery( "#pressme" ).on( 'mousedown', function( e ) {
        start = new Date().getTime();
    } );

    jQuery( "#pressme" ).on( 'mouseleave', function( e ) {
        start = 0;
    } );

    jQuery( "#pressme" ).on( 'mouseup', function( e ) {
        if ( new Date().getTime() >= ( start + longpress )  ) {
           alert('long press!');   
        } else {
           alert('short press!');   
        }
    } );

}());
```

Comment: perfect ! I love it. Exactly what I want.

Comment: This code wouldn't work for multiple <div>s or multiple clicks, as the variable *start* is global, and never cleared.

Comment: Creadiff, note the immediately invoked anonymous function wrapper. There's no global leakage in this code.

Comment: I tried to do your code on a href="/page", it works but after the alert I'm redirecting to "/page". Even with a `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Hmm, `preventDefault` should do it (also might be worth throwing a `stopPropigation` in there). Are you event binding to the `anchor` element itself or a div/button around it? Possible the event is bubbling up to your listener and has already fires the location update.

Comment: @editor: when I said global, I was referring to the fact that the starting time is not particularly linked to the clicked object, but stays outside. For example, if your selector involved many elements (like, say, `'div'`), their respective clicks would interfere _via_ the value of `start`.

Comment: Tip: this solution can also be useful if you have a draggable element that should also present an optional menu/div. If user clicks quickly (say, below 500 ms), you should show a menu. If mouseup occurs after 500 ms, do not show the menu (user is still clicking and probably wants to drag).

Comment: The `e.preventDefault()` would need to be in the `.on('click')` event handler.

Comment: This solution is not really correct. In Chrome, if you long press the backwards/forwards navigation buttons in the browser, you get a popup of your browser history links. You do not perform a mouseup to get that list. The long press should only work with a mousedown event.

Answer (score 38):

Add a throttle that only allows the click to happen after 2 seconds of mousedown.

```
var timer;
$('div').on("mousedown",function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        alert("WORKY");
    },2*1000);
}).on("mouseup mouseleave",function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Edit: I added mouseleave too since if the mouse leaves the element and then triggers mouseup, it won't stop the timer.

Comment: Your answer is pretty cool but didn't work on mobile for me. This worked for me: https://github.com/vaidik/jquery-longpress/blob/32718e9afc22ba98894db206455f1fa980f52b89/jquery.longpress.js

Comment: @Does this work with a saparate single click too ?

Comment: @Hunt not sure I understand

Answer (score 4):

In the two years since this question was asked an awesome plugin called jQuery Finger was invented:

http://ngryman.sh/jquery.finger/

```
$('div').on('press', function(e) {
    console.log(this, e);
});
```

Comment: Link that you provided has error in console "jQuery is not defined".

Comment: I get no errors at all :) The code is very good, so thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is pretty old now, but I was looking for something like this and found that Buley's answer was close to what I needed.  I figured I'd post what I've done with it to have it function without the mouse up, sort of like an Android longtouch.

```
// Set the duration of the long press and declare a couple variables
var longpress = 1000;
var start;
var divMouseDown;                       

// Check for mousedown on the element of choice
$("#element").on('mousedown', function(e){
  // Get the time it was clicked
  start = new Date().getTime();

  // See if mouse is still being held down after the longpress duration
  divMouseDown = setTimeout(function(){
    // What we want to happen when mouse is clicked and held for 1 second
  }, longpress);

  // If the mouse leaves the element or is released before the long touch event, 
  // reset variables and stop the function from triggering          
  $("#element").on('mouseup mouseleave', function(){
    if (divMouseDown) {
      clearTimeout(divMouseDown);
    }
    start = 0;
    e.stopPropagation();
  } );

} );
```

Answer (score 3):

> Short-click & Long-click events - short press prevented in long press

```
//from e-OS menu script
var longpress = 800;
var start;
var timer;

//short press - show e-OS system menu
//long press - show e-OS settings
$( "#e-OS-menu" ).on( 'mousedown', function( e ) {
    start = new Date().getTime();
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ console.log('long press!'); }, longpress)
}).on( 'mouseleave', function( e ) {
    start = 0;
    clearTimeout(timer);
}).on( 'mouseup', function( e ) {
    if ( new Date().getTime() < ( start + longpress )  ) {
       clearTimeout(timer);
       console.log('short press!');   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

So this is obviously a long way in the future, but for people who want to do this still, a super simple and pretty elegant way to do this is by combining the clearTimeout function with mouseup / mouseout events:

```js
$('#button').mousedown(function(){
   var timer = setTimeout(
    () => {alert('long press occurred');}, 600
   );
}).mouseup(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
}).mouseout(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

```css
#button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">press here</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code (tested in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNmmc/)):

```
$('#foo').mousedown(function(){
   $(this).data('lastPressed', new Date().getTime());
}).mouseup(function(){
    var lastPressed = $(this).data('lastPressed');
    if (lastPressed){
        var duration = new Date().getTime() - lastPressed;
        $(this).data('lastPressed', false);
        if (duration > 2000) {
            alert('Your click lasted more than 2 seconds.');
        } else {
            alert('Your click lasted less than 2 seconds.');
        }
    }
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).data('lastPressed', false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading and merging *Editor* and *Kevin B* replies you can have a fully functional, multi divs, hold-catcher with:

```
    // Global delta msec timeout
    var delta = 1500;

    $("#foo").on('mousedown', function(event) {

        var thisElement = $(event.currentTarget);
        var deltaTimer = setTimeout(function(){

            console.log('long press!');
            thisElement.removeData('startTimestamp');
        }, delta);

        thisElement.data('startTimestamp', new Date().getTime());
        thisElement.data('timer', deltaTimer);
    }).on('mouseleave', function(event) {

        var thisElement = $(event.currentTarget);
        clearTimeout(thisElement.data('timer'));

        thisElement.removeData('startTimestamp');
        thisElement.removeData('timer');
    }).on('mouseup', function(event) {

        var thisElement = $(event.currentTarget);
        var startTimestamp = thisElement.data('startTimestamp');
        clearTimeout(thisElement.data('timer'));

        if (startTimestamp !== undefined && !isNaN(parseInt(startTimestamp))) {

            if (new Date().getTime() >= (startTimestamp + delta))
               console.log('long press!');
            else
               console.log('short press!');
        }

        thisElement.removeData('startTimestamp');
        thisElement.removeData('timer');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution executes the action after the time you set. It also cancels the action if you leave the pressed element with the mouse.

```
var longpress={
        pressed:false,
        longpressed:false,
        presstime:1000
    };

$('#element').on( 'mousedown' , function( event ) {
        longpress.longpressed=false;
        longpress.pressed=true;
        longpress.timeout=setTimeout(function() {
            longpress.longpressed=true;
            //Long press action here!
        },longpress.presstime);
    }).on( 'mouseup' , function( event ) {
        clearTimeout(longpress.timeout);
        if (!longpress.longpressed && longpress.pressed) {
            longpress.pressed=false;
            //Short press action here!
        }
    }).on('mouseleave', function( event ) {
        clearTimeout(longpress.timeout);
        longpress.pressed=false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the timestamp when you detect the click on the div thanks to `mousedown`. Similarly you can get the timestamp when you detect the click release thanks to `mouseup`.

You then need to compare these two timestamps, if they are greater than 2 seconds (or 2000milliseconds) then you execute your function.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. No need for long uneccesary coding.

```
(function(){
    // how many milliseconds is a long press?
    var offset = 500;

    $(".button").on('mousedown', function(e){
        // holds the start time
        $(this).data('start',new Date().getTime());
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }).on('mouseup', function(e){
        if (new Date().getTime() >= ($(this).data('start') + offset)){
            //alert('ur click lasted for over 2 secs');
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
    }).on('mouseleave', function(e){
        start = 0;
        //you can add destroy lingering functions on mouse leave
    });

}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/donddoug/8D4nJ/

Comment: When I tried this on my iOS device the default contextMenu popped up and I saw no trace of this working unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate the time difference when the mouse clicks and leave. We can get the `timestamp` when you click and release a `button` or `div`  using `mousedown` and `mouseup`

Here's an example to detect the simple click and `2 seconds` long press. Here I have done with a `button` press. Similarly, you can use `div`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var pressTime; // store the press time

    $("#pressHere").on('mouseup', function () {

        var holdTime = 2000; //  2 seconds for long press

        if (new Date().getTime() >= (pressTime + holdTime))
            $("#status").text("It's a Long Press...");
        else
            $("#status").text("It's a Short Press...");
      
    }).on('mousedown', function () { // When Button Release
        
    pressTime = new Date().getTime();
    
    }).on('mouseleave', function () {   // When Button Leave
        
    pressTime = 0;
    
    });

});
```

```css
.input-bar-item {
    display: table-cell;
}
.button-item {
margin: 20px;
    width: 30%;
}
.width100 {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <div class="input-bar-item button-item">
      <button class="btn btn-info" id="pressHere">Press Me</button>
</div>
<div class="input-bar-item width100" id="status"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution

- supports touch and click
- makes sure only click or longClick is fired and only once
- is canceled when mouse/finger is moved away from element
- suppresses copy/paste being triggered on touch devices
- requires jQuery
- tested with jquery 3.6.0

Usage:

```js
    $("#button").longClick(
       function() { //longclick callback
           console.log("long clicked");
       }, 
       function() { //click callback (optional)
           console.log("clicked");
       },
       1000 //Time in ms. Optional
    });
```

JSFillde: https://jsfiddle.net/01em4yvc/

Code:

```js
    
    (function() {
       /**
        * Register a function to handle long click via mouse or touch
        *
        * @author Torge Kummerow
        */
        $.fn.longClick = function (longClickCallback, clickCallback = null, timeout = 1000) {
            if (longClickCallback == null && clickCallback == null)
                throw new Error("Neither longClickCallback nor clickCallback defined");
            
            let _t = this; //Nailing this to _t for all following function contexts
            
            //Struct to keep track of the state.
            let state = {
                started : false,
                triggered : false,
                timer : null,
                
                clear : function () {
                    state.started = false;
                    state.triggered = false;
                    if (state.timer != null)
                        clearTimeout(state.timer);
                    state.timer = null;
                }
            }
            
            //Disable native longpress touch handling on touch devices (like copy/paste)
            $(_t).css({
                '-webkit-touch-callout' : 'none',
                '-webkit-user-select'   : 'none',
                '-khtml-user-select'    : 'none',
                '-moz-user-select'      : 'none',
                '-ms-user-select'       : 'none',
                'user-select'           : 'none'
            });
        
            //Handling events
            $(_t).on('mousedown mouseup mouseout touchstart touchend touchcancel touchmove', function(event) {
                switch (event.type) {
                    case 'touchstart' :
                    case 'mousedown' :
                        if (state.started)
                            return; //Click handling alread in progress. A touch will trigger both touchstart and mousedown (but mousedown only after touchend)
                            
                        state.clear(); //To be safe
                        state.started = true;
                        
                        //starting a timer when to handle the long press
                        state.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                            //User pressed for long enough to handle the press
                            if (longClickCallback != null && state.started && !state.triggered) {
                                state.triggered = true;
                                longClickCallback(event);
                            }
                        }, timeout);
                        break;
                        
                    case 'touchend' :
                    case 'mouseup' :
                        if (clickCallback != null && state.started && !state.triggered) {
                            //No long press or click handled yet, So fire normal click event if callback was provided
                            state.triggered = true;
                            clickCallback(event);
                        }
                        
                        /*  Delay clearing state because the event order is
                         *  touchstart ... touchend mousedown mouseup
                         *  if not done this way, mousedown will trigger a second click
                         *  This also means the user can only click once every 100 ms which should be fine normally
                         */
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            state.clear();
                        }, 100);
                        
                        break;
                        
                    case 'mouseout' :
                    case 'touchcancle' :
                        // Cancel progress as mouse was moved outside of the element or finger outside of the canvas
                        state.clear();
                        break;
                        
                    case 'touchmove' :
                        // There is no touchout event, so we check ourself if the user is still above the element after
                        // moving. Note that with scrollable content, this will always return false, even if the finger
                        // actually is outside, as the scroll area is ment to move with the finger.
                        // This is especially happening for "rubberband" effects at the edge of scrollable content
                        let x = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
                        let y = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
                        let elBelowMouse = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
                        if ($(_t)[0] != elBelowMouse) {
                            state.clear();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            });
            
            
            return this;
        };
        
    })();
```