# How to create a mouse press in Jquery developing an application to Mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, mousepress

I'm new in Jquery.

I'm developing a mobile application with HTML5 + CSS and JQUERY,

If I go to develop an application for Android with native code, 
for example: I can use a function on listview, when the user presses  for some seconds an action happens , so I'd like to do same event , but with jquery.

I have this div

```
<div class="perform-mouse-press"> hsjashja </div>
```

When I click on it I would like to do something like this :

```
 //Holding some seconds , but the user is pressing the div
$(".perform-mouse-press).mousepress(function(){

     //Doing something...

  });
```

Has somebody any idea how can I do it ?

Comment: There are already threads about element long press. Is this the sort of behavior you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586883/how-to-detect-a-long-press-on-a-div-in-jquery

Comment: Sim, acho que é isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but I'll give it a go...

Your most likely just look for a click event - https://api.jquery.com/click/

```
$('.perform-mouse-press').click(function (){
        //launch rocket ship
});
```

Even better is to use the on method (way better for binding and unbinding) - http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('.perform-mouse-press').on('click',function (){
        //launch rocket ship
});
```

Alternatively if your looking to capture any (left, right or middle) mouse click/down events you could look at using `mousedown` which is used exactly the same as `click` and can, and should be, used in an `on ()` method to bind to an element - https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

EDIT: @Franciscos H link to - [How to detect a long press on a div in Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586883/how-to-detect-a-long-press-on-a-div-in-jquery) is the correct way to detect a long click, personally I prefer the implementation using a combination of `mousedown`, `mouseup` and setTimout (below the accepted answer)

Comment: The OP wants to detect a long press, not a click/tap.

Comment: I'm using now this mousedown I did a combination between mousedown and mouseup , I make a counting  of time, for example if I clic on the element I start to count and when the mouse leaves the element depending on the time the function is fired

Comment: Yup, that's the way to go. If you need another example feel free to consult the thread I linked to your question.

Comment: I found this site http://ngryman.sh/jquery.finger/.  there are lots of components there,  including press , so this event works as I wanted